# Start bottom border 20px from the left of the div

Tags: html, css

```
<style>
.dt-product-line {
    padding-left: 20px;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-style: dashed;

}
</style>    

<div class="dt-product-line">This is my text</div>
```

I would like to have the bottom line only to appear from the text on to the rest of the div.
this css is underlining the complete div, while the text is indented 20px.

how can i also let the border bottom line start from 20px like the text?

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap your text in a [`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) tag and style that instead

```css
.dt-product-line {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.underline {
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-style: dashed;
}
```

```html
<div class="dt-product-line"><span class="underline">This is my text</span></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to solve this,

One solution is, Enclose your line and text div with outer div which takes the required padding-left.

```
<style>
  .dt-product-line-outer {
     padding-left: 20px;
  }
  .dt-product-line {
     border-bottom-width: 2px;
     border-bottom-style: dashed;
  }
</style>

<div class="dt-product-line-outer">
  <div class="dt-product-line">This is my text</div>
</div>
```